# Keep filter/detail pane open - SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, document-library

Is there a way to keep one of panes open in a SharePoint Library or List in the modern pages?

Usually when I keep open them, the next library/list I open will remain opened but that is not happening for my IE, for example.

Is there any cookie that sets that?